# OverlapBox returns null almost every time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried to make a script to spawn objects at a random position without them colliding with one another. It doesn't work properly as the OverlapBox returns almost every time null even when it touches a square.

**Here is the script:**

```cs
var quadBoundaries = quad.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().bounds;
var squareRadius = new Vector2(1, 1);

        foreach (var square in squaresToSpawn)
        {
            _isOverlapping = true;
            while (_isOverlapping)
            {
                _spawnPoint = new Vector2(Random.Range(quadBoundaries.min.x + 1.5f, quadBoundaries.max.x - 1.5f), 
                    Random.Range(quadBoundaries.min.y + 1.5f, quadBoundaries.max.y - 1.5f));

                _collisionWithSquare = Physics2D.OverlapBox(_spawnPoint, squareRadius, 
                    0, LayerMask.GetMask("Square Layer"));

                if (_collisionWithSquare is null)
                {
                    square.transform.position = _spawnPoint;
                    _isOverlapping = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

The **quadBoundaries** are the boundaries of a quad I placed so the squares will randomly spawn in a limited space.
My understanding is that I am generating a random point in the quad boundaries and then I check if on that point a square of scale (1,1) will fit without touching any other thing that has a collider and is on the square layer. if it touches then I generate a new point until the collision is null so I can place the square at the designated position.
But a bunch of things that I don't understand are happening.
**First**, the squares are touching each other. **Second**, just a few specific squares are registering a collision but even those are being touched by other squares. **Third**, when I scale up the square radius (for example 10,10) I get a big split between the squares (shown in the picture bellow).

[image: radius= (10,10)]

I must add that all squares have a collider, are all on the square layer and the quad is on a different layer.
Can anybody explain to me what I'm not getting here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show a picture from the scene view with all quad and squares selected?

Comment: With the same radius as shown above?

Comment: If the square size in the picture is 10x10, you know the area 1x1 is only 1%, so the test probably returns null.

Comment: the white squares' sizes are all (1,1) but the radius of the OverlapBox is (10,10). when I put the radius of the OverlapBox at (1,1) then I get a bunch of squares spawning randomly on top of each other

Comment: Where are your squares in the beginning before you hit Play? I.e. in your loop, can they already collide with non-positioned squares? Also note your code has potential for an infinite loop if no possible place is left (once it's otherwise fixed), which you can avoid by giving it a max-tries counter break. You may also consider changing squareRadius to use the actual square size instead, eliminating another possible source of error. Good luck.

Comment: my squares are all in the middle. This is just a case test to see if they will collide, normally i will only have 7 squares. the radius has been put to (10, 10) just to see it would react in order to understand what is happening better. Normally the radius is the same size as all the squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the answer I'd like to say, that such algorithm of spawning is very dangerous, because you can enteran infinity loop, when there will no be place for new square. Minimum, that you can do to make this code more safe is to add a retries count for finding a place to spawn. But I will leave it on your conscience.

To make this algorithm work, you should understand that all physics in Unity are updated in fixed update. So all operations, that you do with `Phisycs` or `Phisics2D` are working with the state of objects, that was performed in the last Pyhsics update. When you change the position of the object, physics core don't capture this changes instantly. As a workaround you can spawn each object in the fixed update separately. Like this:

```cs
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _squaresToSpawn;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _quad;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }

    private IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        var quadBoundaries = _quad.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().bounds;
        var squareRadius = new Vector2(1, 1);
        Vector2 spawnPoint;
        
        foreach (var square in _squaresToSpawn)
        {
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
            var isOverlapping = true;
            var retriesCount = 10;
            while (isOverlapping && retriesCount > 0)
            {
                
                spawnPoint = new Vector2(Random.Range(quadBoundaries.min.x + 1.5f, quadBoundaries.max.x - 1.5f), 
                    Random.Range(quadBoundaries.min.y + 1.5f, quadBoundaries.max.y - 1.5f));

                var hit = Physics2D.OverlapBox(spawnPoint, squareRadius,
                    0, LayerMask.GetMask("Square"));
                
                if (hit is null)
                {
                    square.transform.position = spawnPoint;
                    isOverlapping = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    retriesCount--;
                    if (retriesCount == 0)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Can't find place to spawn the object!!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

But such code will have effect of continious spawning:
[image]

To make objects spawning properly within one frame. You should manualy store all spawned objects bounding boxes inside your code, and manualy check if your new spawn bounding box collide with previously spawned objects.

Comment: Thank you so much man! I would not worry about the infinity loop since I'll end up spawning 7 squares only and there is no configuration where 6 squares can take too much space for the 7th to spawn. Thanks again.

Comment: As an addition: Instead of spreading the spawns over multiple frames which might be awkward and undesired you can manually call [`Physics2D.Simulate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Simulate.html) to force a physics update without actually waiting for the next frame: `Phyiscs2D.simulationMode = SimulationMode2D.Script; Physics2D.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);`

Comment: @derHugo, I strongly don't recoment use such things. Especialy if you have no understanding of custom phichics pipelines design. By setting `Phyiscs2D.simulationMode = SimulationMode2D.Script;` you say to Unity like: "Go ahead! I know better then you how my physics should be simulated!". And right after this you pass `Time.fixedDeltaTime` to the `Physics2D.Simulate`, that is an error, actually. You should calculate the time manually, base on system time, time scale, and maybe other factors.

Comment: The correct way to use `Physics2D.Simulate` will be like `Physics2D.simulationMode = SimulationMode2D.Script; Physics2D.Simulate(0f); Physics2D.simulationMode = SimulationMode2D.FixedUpdate;`

Comment: well almost ... you would keep the mode set for the entire loop and reset it afterwards I guess ;) I would strongly recommend to rather assume that a map etc shall be spawned in a single frame and not across multiple ones especially if this is in `Start` and only happening once. You are right about the time .. didn't know that `0` would be valid ... the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Simulate.html) itself uses `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. There is no need to base this on system time as it is a **step**